# Prevent page pop on tab change in Onsen UI

Tags: cordova, tabs, onsen-ui

I just started using Onsen UI and I downloaded the tab-bar template from the website. The tab-bar template has 2 "main" pages: timeline and settings.

I have added a child page to the "timeline" page, which I am calling using myNavigator.push(....).

My structure now is like this:

- timeline

> child
>
> settings
>
> Let's supposed now I am displaying the timeline > child page: when I click on the settings tab I am obviosly taken to the settings page. Now, from the settings page I want to return to the previous page (child in the timeline stack), the link takes me back to the parent page (timeline).

I would like to keep active the last page visited in that stack, in my case the child page, is there an easy way to do it?

Sorry, maybe a bit messy, I hope you guys will understand what I mean.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found out of the answer, I post it here for future references.

from the guide: use the "persistent" atribute:

```
<ons-tab active="true" page="home.html" persistent>
  <div class="tab">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
    <div class="tab-label">Home</div>
  </div>
</ons-tab>

<ons-tab page="settings.html" persistent>
  <div class="tab">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
    <div class="tab-label">Settings</div>
  </div>
</ons-tab>
```